# Devrait-on avoir une bannière indiquant notre politique concernant le contenu généré par IA ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Il y a eu une [annonce](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881) au sujet d'une bannière qu'on peut mettre en place et qui affiche un message quand quelqu'un répond à une question :

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [site_particulier.SE]. Learn more.

Et le lien « Learn more » renvoie à une page comme [celle-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), qui pourrait certainement être en français et en anglais. Je ne sais pas si on peut avoir le message de rappel dans les deux langues, mais si oui, je propose :

> **Rappel**: Les réponses générées au moyen d'outils d'intelligence artificielle sont interdites sur French.SE. Pour en savoir plus.

Je vous invite à lire l'annonce et ce que ça implique et à créer des réponses particulières.

---

There was an [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881) about a banner we can set up that displays a message when someone answers a question:

**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [specific_site.SE]. Learn more.

And the "Learn more" link goes to a page like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), which could certainly be in both French and English. I don't know if we can have the reminder message in both languages, but if so, I suggest :

> **Rappel**: Les réponses générées au moyen d'outils d'intelligence artificielle sont interdites sur French.SE. Pour en savoir plus.

I invite you to read the announcement and what it implies, and to create your own answers.

Comment: Related and without an official answer, j'attends https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/908/1893. What is our AI policy?

Answer (score 4):

**Oui**, nous devrions avoir une telle bannière ou une variante de cette bannière (voir annonce). / **Yes**, we should have such a banner or a variant thereof (see announcement).

Answer (score 1):

**Non**, nous ne devrions pas avoir une telle bannière ou une variante de cette bannière (voir annonce). / **No**, we should not have such a banner or a variant thereof (see announcement).